# How to add Facebook App (webpage) as Tab on Facebook page

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps, facebook-page, facebook-tabs

I have looked at existing questions but found nothing that answers my questions.

I have an app on facebook (its actually a webpage added as an app). I have added Page Tab as a platform. I also have a page for the app.

Now, I am trying to add this app to another page, as a tab.

I am not finding any way to do this right now. When trying to manage tabs, I can add apps. But I only see "notes" as an option. Any idea how to do that ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs tell you how to add an App to a Page: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/tabs#adding

For example, open this in your browser with the appropriate parameters:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_URL
```

...you will see a list of all Pages you manage and you can add the App to those.